# Calling View LaunchedEffect multiple times inside LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to trigger the LaunchedEffect event in only one of the views in the LazyColumn, but the LaunchedEffect is triggered in all views, so the UI of all views changes.

```kotlin
LazyColumn(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(horizontal = 30.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
) {
    items(postData.size) {
        Column {
            Post(postData = postData[it], index = it)
            HorizontalDivider(
                color = CustomColor.Gray,
                thickness = 1.dp,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 20.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
fun Post(
    postData: PostData, viewModel: PostViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val postGoodCounts = rememberSaveable { mutableLongStateOf(postData.goodCounts) }
    val goodStatus = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(postData.goodStatus ?: false) }

    val postImage = postData.postImage

    //api postGood
    viewModel.postGood(
    postData.postId 
    )

    //When postGood API completes successfully
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        viewModel.postGoodState.collect {
            if (it.isSuccess) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. However, if you want to trigger a `LaunchedEffect` only for one `Post` item, you can wrap the `LaunchedEffect` inside a condition like this:

```
fun Post(
    postData: PostData, 
    index: Int,
    viewModel: PostViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val postGoodCounts = rememberSaveable { mutableLongStateOf(postData.goodCounts) }
    val goodStatus = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(postData.goodStatus ?: false) }

    val postImage = postData.postImage

    //api postGood
    viewModel.postGood(
    postData.postId 
    )

    if (index == 0) {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            viewModel.postGoodState.collect {
                if (it.isSuccess) {
                    //...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I added the `index` parameter to the `Post` Composable. You pass the index in the first code snippet you provided, but don't include it in the `Post` function signature.

With this code, the `LaunchedEffect` will be executed once for the first item. However, when scrolling, and the first item is recycled for another item, when you then scroll back up, it could be executed a second time.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple just used **LaunchEffect** with **Unit** It's only Running one line.

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    //your code 
}
```